# Reactjs: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jhipster

I have the following code:
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjv21.png)

ERROR OCCURED:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLtVX.png)

I'm using:

- "generator-jhipster": "6.10.4"
- "webpack": "4.43.0",
- "webpack-cli": "3.3.11",
- "webpack-dev-server": "3.10.3",

Comment: Hi @Saber, I think you need to check code in `social-login.js` instead your `App.js`